# Popup will show in the outlook for unwanted recipient

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a list of 150 people and I don't want to send any email apart from the list. Is it possible to set a macro in the outlook where if I try to send any email to the email id which is not present in the list, I will get a popup before sending the email ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can handle the `ItemSend` event of the Application class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an `Inspector` (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the `Send` method for an Outlook item, such as `MailItem` , is used in a program.

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 

Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
  Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application 
End Sub 

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
  Dim prompt As String 
  prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " &; Item.Subject &; "?" 
  If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 
    Cancel = True 
  End If 
End Sub
```

Instead of simply displaying a message box asking users permissions to send an Outlook item you may check the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-recipients-property-outlook) collection (see the corresponding property of the Outlook item). It represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. So, you may check them and compare with your list.

Comment: It seems from the above code that the popup will show for all the emails however I don't want to see the popup for all the emails. I have a list of 150 people, so the popup will only show when I try to send the emails to the person who is not in the list of 150 people. Is it possible ?

Comment: Can someone please help me on this. The code is not working

Comment: You need to add a condition where you compare the item being sent with your list of items.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It would be great if you could please share the code with me.